# How to determine whether output iterator has been modified

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a template function that takes the following form:

```
template < class ITER1, class ITER2 >
bool example(ITER1 Input1, ITER1 Input2, ITER2 Output)
{
    ITER2 OrigOutput(Output);

    // ...

    std::copy(Input1, Input2, Output);

    return (OrigOutput != Output);
}
```

And I'm calling `example()` like this:

```
std::vector < int > Input;
std::set < int > Output;

if (example(Input.begin(), Input.end(), inserter(Output, Output.begin())))
{
    ...
}
```

I'd like `example()` to return `true` if elements have been inserted into `Output`, however I'm getting a compile error (msvc 2008):

```
Error 1 error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand 
operand of type 'std::insert_iterator<_Container>' (or there is no acceptable 
conversion)
```

**Is there a way I can determine whether any elements were inserted into the output iterator in order to return the correct bool value?**

Comment: Couldn't you do return Input1 != Input2;? In other, more specific cases, you could set a flag if anything was inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a wrapper iterator which delgates to another iterator, which you would construct from your insert iterator. Your delegate then can set a `modified` member to be true in the `operator=` method.

Something along the lines of this:

```
template<typename ITER>
class ModifiedIterator : public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
{
protected:
    typedef ITER Iter;
    Iter iter;
    bool& isModified;

public:
    explicit ModifiedIterator (Iter i, bool& isMod)
    : iter(i), isModified (isMod)
    {}

    template<typename T>
    ModifiedIterator& operator= (const T& value)
    {
        iter = value;
        ++iter;
        isModified = true;
        return *this;
    }

    ModifiedIterator& operator* () { return *this; }
    ModifiedIterator& operator++ () { return *this; }
    ModifiedIterator operator++ (int) { return *this; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

OutputIterators don't allow that.  But in your case, what prevent you to return `Input1 != Input2`?

Comment: This is an example function to illustrate my problem - I'd like to determine whether the output iterator has had anything inserted into it

Comment: Again, you can't.  Nothing in the requirement section of OutputIterator allow to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least the following two options:

1. Write your own version  `inserter` which takes an extra boolean reference parameter as an argument which is set to true if `cont.insert (...).second` is true.
2. Before the 'if' statement in the caller code, store the size of the container.  If it has more elements after the call, then you know that the copy inserted elements.

The second options has potential performance considerations if the cost of size is not O(1).